# Match files which are not in a specific directory

Tags: nginx

I have the following rule in my nginx config:

```
location ~* .(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|xml|swf|flv|eot|ttf|woff|pdf|xls|htc)$ {
```

which matches some images and other resources. However I want to prevent it to match resources which are in a specific directory `uploads`. How would I change the above rule to prevent matching files in the `uploads` directory (like `/uploads/something.jpg`), but still match file like `/anything/whatever.jpg` or just `whatever.jpg`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`location ~* ^\/(?!(upload\/)).*(js|css|png|blahblah)$`